Volume integral of vector field in spherical and cartesian coordinates
I am trying to reconcile the different results obtained when integrating a vector field in either spherical or cartesian coordinates.
Take for example the vector field in spherical coordinates (physics convention) to be
$$
\vec{F}(r,\theta,\phi)=e^{-r}\hat{r}+e^{-r} \sin (\theta )\hat{\theta}+e^{-r} r \sin (\theta ) \hat{\phi}
$$
then the volume integral is
$$
\vec{f}_\mathrm{sphe}=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\vec{F}(r,\theta,\phi)r^2\sin{(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi=8\pi\hat{r}+2\pi^2\hat{\theta}+ 6\pi^2 \hat{\phi}\;\;(1)
$$
In both cases, I am not exactly sure if the notation with the unit vectors is actually correct.
Now, I get for the $\vec{F}$ transformed to cartesian coodinates the expression (using $r$ to make it more concise):
$$
\vec{F}(x,y,z)=e^{-r} \left(\frac{x (r+z)}{r^2}-y\right)\hat{x}+e^{-r} \left(\frac{y
   (r+z)}{r^2}+x\right)\hat{y}+e^{-r} \left(\frac{z (r+z)}{r^2}-1\right)\hat{z}
$$
Due to the antisymmetry of the first two components, only the $\hat{z}$ component is non-zero:
$$
\vec{f}_\mathrm{cart}=\int\int\int \vec{F}(x,y,z)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y,\mathrm{d}z=0\hat{x}+0\hat{y}+\frac{-16\pi}{3}\hat{z}\;\;(2)
$$
Now I don't know how to go from the result of $(1)$ to $(2)$. I would think the transformation should involve the Jacobian matrix, similar to how $\vec{F}$ was transformed in the first place (i.e. like in this question), but I don't get what I should put for $r,\theta,\phi$ here then, since I've already integrated.
I also tried the case where only $F_\phi$ is non-zero, then only the $\hat{\phi}$-component of $\vec{f}_\mathrm{sphe}$ in $(1)$ remains of course, but $\vec{f}_\mathrm{cart}$ in $(2)$ is altogether zero. Which I guess is fine, because the magnitude of $\vec{f}_\mathrm{sphe}$ is zero if I understand that correctly? At least, I would expect the integral to be zero, because the field is circular.
I am sure that I am missing something simple and fundamental here.
Edit: But I don't think it's the same problem as in Calculate divergence ∇⋅F in spherical coordinates, where the transformation of $\vec{F}$ to the cartesian basis was the issue. But maybe the related problem is, that I can't make sense of transforming $\vec{f}_\mathrm{sphe}$ to a cartesian vector, which makes it dependent on coordinates again if done like for the vector field.

Does this answer your question? Calculate divergence $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$ in spherical coordinates

@KurtG. Thanks for the link. I hope I got the transformation of $\vec{F}$ from cartesian to spherical coordinates correctly here, which, as I understand it, was the problem there. If I apply the same transformation to $f_\mathrm{sphe}$ though, it becomes dependent on $x,y,z$ and I can't make sense of it, especially since setting $x,y,z=0$ leads to indeterminate results.

The calculation of $(1)$ is incorrect because you still have the spherical unit vectors at the end of the computation having treated them as constants. The only unit system with constant unit vectors is Cartesian coordinates. $\hat{r},\hat{\theta},$ and $\hat{\phi}$ are functions to integrate, not constants.

$\textbf{Hint:}$ As stated in the comments, your spherical coordinate computations are all done incorrectly. As an example, let's work through the $\hat{r}$ component:
$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^3}e^{-r}\hat{r}dV = \int_{\Bbb{R}^3}e^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}dV = 0$$
We don't need to go through the entire computation - it is clear that the integrand is an odd function in any of the three variables we choose, thus the function integrates to $0$ by symmetry. Can you continue with the proper integration from here?

Thanks, I knew the spherical unit vectors were functions of the coordinates, but I somehow ignored it the whole time. But basically this means that one always needs to transform to cartesian unit vector basis before integrating, since your equation is simply the result of the Jacobian transformation of the vector field, right? So my result $(2)$ was the (only) correct way to do it, I gather.

And if I want to get the result to spherical unit vectors, i.e. $\vec{f}\mathrm{sphe}$, I apply the Jacobian again and choose some value for $\theta,\phi$, because the unit vectors depend on that. So here for $\theta=0$, $\vec{f}\mathrm{sphe}=-16/3\pi \hat{r}$,
